# How to set the VPC up so that all the inside EC2 use the same EIP to communicate with exterior?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc

This is a basic question, please bear with me.
I am trying to setup a vpc where all the EC2 instances will be able to communicate to the world via the same IP adress. Same like on a home network, all the computers will have the same Public IP.
How to set that. NAT or Network Interface or ?

## aws

Answer (score 1):

You can use NAT gateway. You can have two subnets in VPC, you can use one subnet(without IGW) to launch all the EC2 instances and you can have a second subnet (public with IGW) and add a NAT gateway to it.
In the routing table attached to private subnet, add a route for 0.0.0.0/0 and point it to NAT gateway.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/nat-gateway-vpc-private-subnet/

NAT gateway only allows outbound traffic, if you would like to connect outside to inside, you need to use NAT gateway.

Comment: Thanks Jaes for your answer. I am testing that and will let you know.
But seems like the last sentence is not correct.

Comment: what I meant to say is the returning traffic is allowed but from example, if you want to setup web server inside ands people can initiate a connection from outside, this won't happen  using NAT gateway.

Comment: Hi James. I am still unable to make it run. I have created the VPC and 2 subnets inside of it. I have created an IGW for the 1st subnet, but that only does not allow access to Internet to its EC2 instances, you have to update the route table of the entire VPC and make 0.0.0.0/0 point to the IGW. DOing that, you immediately affect the 2nd subnet which is supposed to be private and have limited access to internet via the NAT... What I need is to be able to connect to the internet via a specific EIP. What do you suggest?

Comment: 1. Subnet 1:  no public ip addresses, routing table 1
2. Subnet 2: it's  create an NAT Gateway and attach  to it, NAT gateway requires EIP , routing table 2 with IGW so we can call it public subnet.
3. In routing table 1, create a route 0.0.0.0/0 --> Nat gateway and thats it.